# Use an existing Servlet Class or JSP - Servlet list is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, servlets

I have the following problem with a small Spring MVC project I'm trying to create. I'd like to create the DispatcherServlet, but the wizard list is empty.

[image]

I believe I have all the necessary dependencies covered:

- spring-core
- spring-beans
- spring-context
- spring-jdbc
- spring-web
- spring-webmvc

I read on similar questions that the wizard can only be used on Dynamic Web projects. I checked the Project Facets and it seems to be OK.

- Dynamic Web Module v3.0
- Java v1.6
- JavaScript v1.0

Also, web.xml has been created and the project has been updated with the Maven dependencies.

As far as I know this should work, but it doesn't. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the DispatcherServlet is not created by the application developer as it´s part of the spring jars. you just need to add it in your web.xml and declare some controllers - see the spring petclinic sample app https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/

Comment: Maybe I should've said "add", more than "create". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.  I just had to select a **Target runtime** when creating the Dynamic Web Project. Once I did that the New Servlet list worked properly and I could add the DispatcherServlet.

Of course, it can also be done manually on web.xml (that's what I did), but I was worried since the other method was supposed to work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should set server runtime in your project. To do that, 
Right click project -> Click properties -> Java Build Path ->Add Library –> Click Next -> Select server and add it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked as below:

1. Brought my server into Targeted Runtime by going into ProjectExplorer--> Properties --> Target Runtime -->  Select the server
2. Then I moved my Web app libraries( I copied Spring jar files in web-inf during setting up the project) from Classpath to modulepath.

Apply and Save. Restart the IDE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Spring mvc IS NOT COMPATIBLE with Tomcat 10. This is because Tomcat 10 is based on Jakarta EE 9 where package names for APIs have changed from javax.* to jakarta.*

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.2/source-code

the solution that is not recommended is to use, is to use tomcat9 (to lower version)
but what i recommend is to install the **jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.2.jar** and go to your project -> right click -> propreties -> java build path - click on classpath -> add external jars and add jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.2.jar to class path then just go create servlet and select existing, browse and you will see all other classes